# mapstruct list<string> TO list<dto>

Tags: mapstruct

```
MenuInterfaceRelation {
    private Long interfaceId;
    private Long otherId;
    ...
}

@Mapping(target = "interfaceId", source = "?")
List<MenuInterfaceRelation> converteTo(List<Long> interfaceIdList);
```

I want to use mapstruct do something like this code.
but i don't know how to coding source part, or make it work by other way.
does anybody know how to make it working by mapstruct?

Answer (score 1):

There is a `List<String>` in a title, but in your model and method I can only see `Long` values, so the simplest way to achieve this will be as follow.

```
@Mapping(target = "interfaceId", source = "interfaceId")
MenuInterfaceRelation convertToMenuInterfaveRelation(Long interfaceId);

List<MenuInterfaceRelation> convertToMenuInterfaveRelationList(List<Long> interfaceIdList);
```

Mapstruct will handle all other logic.